# under what conditions $|z-a|+|z-b|=c$ and $|b-a| \gt c$ Represents Hyperbola

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

under what conditions $|z-a|+|z-b|=c$ and $|b-a| \gt c$ Represents Hyperbola

Suppose if i take $$|z-1|+|z+1|=0.5$$ then we have

$$|z-1|=0.5-|z+1|$$

Squaring both sides

$$|z|^2+1-2Re(z)=0.25+|z|^2+1+2Re(z)-|z+1|$$ So

$$4x+0.25=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}$$  again squaring we get

$$16x^2-\frac{16}{15}y^2=1$$ which is Hyperbola

so is it true if $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|b-a| \gt c$ then $$|z-a|+|z-b|=c$$ represents hyperbola

Comment: Never. $|z-a|+|z-b|\geq|z-a-z+b|=|a-b|>c$. So, no points satisfy those two conditions.

Comment: ok fine then what is the mistake i have done algebraically

Comment: No mistake. You started from a false equality, did valid transformations and reached another equation. $-1=1$. Square both sides $1=1$. The question is whether you can go backwards.

Comment: For example, take a point in the hyperbola at the end. $z=(1/4,0)$ is one such point. When we compute $|z-1|=3/4$, $|z+1|=5/4$. Therefore $|z-1|+|z+1|=8/4=2\neq 0.5$. Those squaring steps in one direction would have to be square roots in the other. But we can't always take square roots and get the equation with the signs we want.

Comment: Your proof does show that any point that satisfies the equality at the beginning must lie on the hyperbola at the end. The question on whether there are actually points that do satisfy that equality or whether all points of the hyperbola satisfy the equality do not follow from the chain of deductions you made.

Comment: i understood clearly now thanks

Comment: @Umeshshankar Same as $|z|=-1 \implies |z|^2=1 \implies x^2+y^2=1\,$, but this does *not* mean that $|z|=-1$ represents the unit circle.